# Replace column_id to column_name of this id

Tags: mysql, select, alias

I'm trying to replace `category_id = 5`, with `category_name = Piłka Nożna`. I tried a lot of queries but nothing works for me. I would be happy if someone can help me to fix it.

- I join two tables by query:

`"SELECT * FROM quizes INNER JOIN categories ON quizes.quiz_category = categories.category_id";`

- When I `console.log(rows)` everything seems fine

```
    quiz_id: 11,
    quiz_category: 5,
    quiz_question: 'Pytanie 3',
    quiz_answer_A: 'A',
    quiz_answer_B: 'B',
    quiz_answer_C: 'C',
    quiz_answer_D: 'D',
    quiz_correct: 'G',
    category_id: 5,
    category_name: 'Piłka Nożna'
```

- Image of my database

[image: Database image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aliases for your fields. For example:

```
SELECT
    quiz_id,
    category_name AS quiz_category,
    quiz_question,
    quiz_answer_A,
    quiz_answer_B,
    quiz_answer_C,
    quiz_answer_D,
    quiz_correct
FROM quizes 
INNER JOIN categories ON quizes.quiz_category = categories.category_id;
```

Or may be:

```
SELECT
    quiz_id,
    category_name AS category_id,
    ...
```

Comment: Great, works perfect! I tough I can skip selecting columns one by one.